# F#: Writing a function that takes any kind of array as input

Tags: arrays, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

Here is part of my code:

```
let splitArrayIntoGroups (inputArray: string[]) (groupSize: int) =
        let groups = new LinkedList<string[]>()
        let rec splitRecursively currentStartIndex currentEndIndex =
            groups.AddLast(inputArray.[currentStartIndex..currentEndIndex]) |> ignore
            let newEndIndex = Math.Min((inputArray.Length - 1), (currentEndIndex + groupSize))
            if newEndIndex <> currentEndIndex then
                splitRecursively (currentStartIndex + groupSize) newEndIndex
        splitRecursively 0 (groupSize - 1)
        groups
```

I want this function to be able to accept arrays of any type (including types that I define myself) as input. What changes should I make?

Comment: I really think you need to read a book / tutorial on F#, rather than just coming to SO so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `string[]` with `_[]` in the function signature.

Comment: There is one other change to make as well.

Comment: you mean leaving out the redundant type annotation in the linked list... But I thought, the general idea would help at least a little...

Answer (score 2):

This was already answered but here you have an implementation not using a linked list but just an array of lists

```
let rec split<'T> (input: 'T array) size =
    let rec loopOn (tail : 'T array) grouped =
        let lastIndex = Array.length tail - 1
        let endindx = min (size - 1) lastIndex
        let arrWrapper = (fun e -> [|e|])
        let newGroup = tail.[0..endindx] 
                        |> List.ofArray
                        |> arrWrapper
                        |> Array.append grouped

        match tail with
            | [||] -> newGroup 
                       |> Array.filter (fun e -> List.length e > 0)
            | _ -> loopOn tail.[endindx + 1..] newGroup

    let initialState = [|List.empty<'T>|]
    loopOn input initialState
```

Because this is generic implementation you can call it with different types

```
type Custom = {Value : int} 

let r = split<int> [|1..1000|] 10
let r2 = split<float> [|1.0..1000.0|] 10

let r3 = split<Custom> [|for i in 1..1000 ->
                            {Value = i}|] 10
```